# Create a quickly app with build dependencies

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I am creating a Quickly app in Ubuntu that depends on [Python Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), which is available in the package **python-twisted**. How should I add python twisted as a dependency so that it will be installed when a user installs my application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The good thing is that Quickly will handle this for you, so you don't have to worry about it at all :)

Once you've added the `import` statement to add Twisted in your code, the next time you run the `quickly package` (or `share` or `release` or `submitubuntu`), Quickly will automatically detect that you're using it and will add it to the dependencies in the `debian/control` file in your source tree.

This will take care of your package pulling in `python-twisted` as a dependency whenever it is installed.

In addition to that, if you really need additional dependencies that you don't use directly in the code, you can use the `quickly configure dependencies` command and add a comma-separated list of extra dependencies to the text editor that's then fired up. Quickly will then always add those dependencies to the package. Be sure to know what you're doing if you're using that command.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I wasn't sure if quickly would automatically add python-twisted as a dependency, or if I would need to edit some file.