# How to add dependencies to a Quickly generated .deb installer?

Tags: application-development, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a quickly app with build dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151928/create-a-quickly-app-with-build-dependencies)

I need extra packages for my app (done with Quickly). When I run:

```
quickly package
```

How can I set them?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional dependencies that aren't detected by Quickly can be added by running

```
quickly configure dependencies
```

Then just add the dependencies to that file and save. The next time you run `quickly package` it will depend on the new dependencies

Comment: Bear in mind that you should separate dependencies with a comma, and be careful not to hit this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/950074

Comment: Btw, if you want to see where the dependencies are added, they're in the `.quickly` file on your project.