# Set dependencies in Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a quickly app with build dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151928/create-a-quickly-app-with-build-dependencies)

As my app for the Developer Showdown, Virtuam, is a GUI assistant for QEMU, I need to indicate to Quickly that QEMU should be installed in Ubuntu. However, there doesn't seems to be any option available in `setup.py`. Then, how can I select the dependencies in a Quickly project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line

```
dependencies = qemu
```

to your project's `.quickly` file. Replace `qemu` with a comma-separated list of whatever packages you need as  dependencies.