# Use MongoDB and PyMongo inside an PyGTK app

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygtk, mongodb

I am abort to make an Python app with Quickly.

The app need to store some data in an database,

To this I am planing to use MongoDB.

**So my question is like this:**

How can I make the py-app to auto install MongoDB and PyMongo,

If the user don´t have this installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you package your application, You'll have to say what extra programs (Dependencies) are needed by you application.

So then when a user installs you program it will check whether all the dependencies are met or not, if not then it will auto install the dependencies.

Here is a guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python

I've not used quickly, but i think the idea should be the same in quickly.

Comment: After reading zerefs answered i find this tread abort quickly and dependencies.. And it look like I just need to do import and quickly will do the rest :-) http://askubuntu.com/questions/151928/create-a-quickly-app-with-build-dependencies