# How can I add a pip based dependency to a Quickly project?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

There is a great topic [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151928/create-a-quickly-app-with-build-dependencies) about dependencies from ubuntu repositories. But my app depends on python package, which has to be install with `sudo pip install package`. Can I add this kind of dependency to my app? Or at least make quickly run this command, when installing  my app?

Edit: This is now filed as a bug [here](http://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/1177894).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't count on the app making it into the main repositories if it were packaged that way.

You could depend on pip and run the pip-install as a post-install hook though.

Comment: Yeah, that is on of possible solutions - but how do I set post-installation commands in quickly? Where should I add them?

Comment: AFAIK You don't "with quickly".  That's the problem with magic tools.

Comment: So, you are saying, you think, it is impossible?

Comment: I'm saying I think it requires manual packaging, not "quickly add-post-inst-cmd 'pip install random-python-awesomeness' && quickly package && quickly push"

Comment: OK, thank you, it seems like a big flaw in Quickly. I am thinking to report it on their bugtracker.

Comment: If you do file it as a bug, make sure you file it as wishlist not defect.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/1177894 - here it is. I can't figure out, where I should set that, it seems, they do it themselves...

Comment: Funny! I tried to add pip as a dependency, but after that my app can't be updated via ppa, because pip is a virtual package. I don't quiet understand, what that means, but I had to remove that dependency.

Comment: enough.  the question was answered http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pip